# Why couldn't I use ' ~ ' instead of ' /home/username/ ' when giving the file path

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I can use `~` instead of `/home/username/` to point to a file path when, for example, unzipping a `.zip` file.

However, today when I followed the same way to run a RNN example in terminal, `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError` was thrown.

```
$ python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models-master/tutorials/rnn/simple-examples/data/ --model=small 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 374, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 321, in main
    raw_data = reader.ptb_raw_data(FLAGS.data_path)
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models-master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py", line 73, in ptb_raw_data
    word_to_id = _build_vocab(train_path)
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models-master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py", line 34, in _build_vocab
    data = _read_words(filename)
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models-master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py", line 30, in _read_words
    return f.read().decode("utf-8").replace("\n", "<eos>").split()
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 106, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 73, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models-master/tutorials/rnn/simple-examples/data/ptb.train.txt
```

Then I replaced `~` with `/home/username/`, and it worked properly.

Why couldn't I use `~` instead of `/home/username/` to point to the file path when runing a RNN example?

Could you tell me in detail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685894/home-directory-expansion-within-an-argument

Comment: [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/146697)

Comment: @OskarSkog Shouldn't the shell expand the `~` before the argument is passed to python? Just like the shell would expand backslash escapes in the path, or remove quotes if the path was quoted.

Comment: Unlike `$VARIABLES`, the `~` is only expanded at the beginning of a string.

Comment: @OskarSkog, "Python does not know what ~ means" implies that an issue is specific to Python lacking a piece of functionality, setting up an unreasonable expectation that such functionality (of performing expansion *after* being `exec`'d) *should* be widely available in UNIX tools.

Comment: @OskarSkog, similarly, "in python, it's like everything is quoted with single quotes" is just untrue if that's intended to be a comparison against any other tool. `echo ~` and `python ~` will both expand the argument in precisely the same way, and `echo --foo=~` and `python --foo=~` will both *fail* to expand in exactly the same way, but "it's like everything is quoted with single quotes" reads as if Python somehow suppresses shell expansion behavior that would otherwise happen pre-invocation.

Comment: @OskarSkog, ...so I literally don't know how your statement can be read to *not* be claiming that Python is somehow at fault for this behavior. (For someone coming from Windows, where command-line parsing from a string into an argument vector is done by the command being invoked rather than the shell doing the invoking, the difference in behavior being on a per-executable basis can even make sense!)

Comment: [Difference between $HOME and ~](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177464/253474), [Why can't I cd to a quoted tilde ('~')?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032370/253474), [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151850/44425)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I cd to a quoted tilde ('~')?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032370/why-cant-i-cd-to-a-quoted-tilde)

Comment: @phuclv The reason tilde expansion isn't performed here has nothing to do with quoting, so I don't think this is a duplicate of a question about how quoting suppresses tilde expansion. There is *some* overlap in material that would answer these questions, but I don't think they qualify as duplicates.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to understand that `~` is normally expanded by the shell; the programs you call never see it, they see the full pathname as inserted by bash. But this only happens when the tilde is at the start of an argument (and is not quoted).

If the Python program you are running uses a module like `getopt` to parse its commandline, you can give the argument of the `--data-path` option as a separate "word" to allow tilde expansion:

```
$ python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/...
```

In your own code, you can use `getopt` or `argparse` for argument processing, and could also manually expand tildes as @JacobVlijm's answer suggested.

PS. The tilde is also expanded at the start of a *shell* variable assignment expression like `DIRNAME=~/anaconda2`; although the tilde in your question also follows an equals sign, this usage doesn't have special meaning for the shell (it's just something passed to a program) and doesn't trigger expansion.

Comment: Unless you *know* `getopt` already, use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) if you're writing Python.

Comment: I've added `argparse` to the answer since it's the main alternative, but personally I find it much harder to use than `getopt`, not easier. YMMV.

Answer (score 39):

#### Tilde expansion in python

The answer is short & simple:

python does not expand `~` unless you use:

```
import os
os.path.expanduser('~/your_directory')
```

See also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html):

> **os.path.expanduser(path)**
>   On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.
>
> On Unix, an initial ~ is replaced by the environment variable HOME if it is set; otherwise the current user’s home directory is looked up in the password directory through the built-in module pwd. An initial ~user is looked up directly in the password directory.

Comment: In general, you should never assume that tilde expansion is done at an OS level, it is something that unix shells (and not all of them!) do for you.

Comment: I think the more relevant issue is lined out in alexis' answer: the position of `~` in the shell argument list.

Comment: @farsil, I disagree. Programs can be made portable, but when you run them from the command line, you do so on a specific system. And let's not forget that this is askubuntu.com, and Ubuntu is always Unix ([as far as we know](https://xkcd.com/424/) :-)

Comment: @alexis: Ubuntu doesn't do tilde expansion at OS level either. It's still shell functionality.

Comment: Methinks you're splitting hairs. Nobody said the kernel is doing it. The point is, it's not done by the program that takes the arguments.

Comment: I agree with David: while the answer is proper as far as Python goes, the key issue here is tilde expansion done by the *shell* (or rather the lack of it in OP's case due to tilde's placement). Now, it should also be pointed out, alexis, that  tilde expansion can be done by the program (as is shown in the documentation quote Jacob provided) and can be of particular use when `HOME` variable is unset (which would be a rare case, but plausible). Also, while this is Ask Ubuntu and we can assume Unix-like environment safely, I think portability and posix-compliance should be upheld more

Comment: Posix compliance, sure. I didn't mean to argue for Ubuntu-only features, just that it's ok to assume Unix. And tilde expansion is not a Windows feature, so there's no expectation that it ought to work there.

Comment: @alexis: You said "I disagree" to the statement "you should never assume that tilde expansion is done at an OS level". That certainly sounds like you're saying the OS does it.

Answer (score 13):

[Tilde expansion is only done in a few contexts that vary slightly between shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/146697).

While it is performed in:

```
var=~
```

Or

```
export var=~
```

in some shells. It's not in

```
echo var=~
env var=~ cmd
./configure --prefix=~
```

in POSIX shells.

It is in `bash` though when not in POSIX conformance mode (like when called as `sh`, or when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment):

```
$ bash -c 'echo a=~'
a=/home/stephane
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= bash -c 'echo a=~'
a=~
$ SHELLOPTS=posix bash -c 'echo a=~'
a=~
$ (exec -a sh bash -c 'echo a=~')
a=~
```

However that's only when what's on the left of the `=` is shaped like an unquoted valid variable name, so while it would be expanded in `cmd prefix=~`, it would not be in `cmd --prefix=~` (as `--prefix` is not a valid variable name) nor in `cmd "p"refix=~` (because of that quoted `p`) nor in `var=prefix; cmd $var=~`.

In `zsh`, you can set the `magic_equal_subst` option for `~` to be expanded after any unquoted `=`.

```
$ zsh -c 'echo a=~'
a=~
$ zsh -o magic_equal_subst -c 'echo a=~'
a=/home/stephane
$ zsh -o magic_equal_subst -c 'echo --a=~'
--a=/home/stephane
```

In the case of `~` (as opposed to `~user`), you can just use `$HOME` instead:

```
cmd --whatever="$HOME/whatever"
```

`~` expands to the value of `$HOME`. If `$HOME` is not set, behaviour varies between shells. Some shells query the user database. If you want to take that into account, you could do (and that's also what you would have to do for `~user`):

```
dir=~ # or dir=~user
cmd --whatever="$dir/whatever"
```

In any case, in shells other than `zsh` remember you need  to quote variable  expansions!

Comment: Bash's [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) seems to say that tildes are expanded only on variable assignments and at the start of a word, so expanding it on`echo a=~` seems to contradict the manual.

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes the manual is incomplete. It also doesn't specify clearly in what context `~` will be expanded (what is meant by "word"). See the link at the top of the answer for more details.

Answer (score 7):

`~` has particular expansion rules, which your command doesn't satisfy. Specifically, it is expanded only when unquoted, either at the beginning of a word (e.g. `python ~/script.py`) or at the beginning of a variable assignment (e.g. `PYTHONPATH=~/scripts python script.py`). What you have is  `--data_path=~/blabla` which is a single word in shell terms, so expansion is not performed.

An immediate fix is to use `$HOME` shell variable, which follows regular variable expansion rules:

```
python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=$HOME/blabla
```

Comment: That's a bit oversimplified, [there are other contexts were tilde expansion is performed](/a/146697) like in `PATH=$PATH:~/bin`. Also that `$HOME` needs to be quoted or split+glob applies in shells other than `zsh`.

Comment: @sch sorry, but the link you provided in the comment there leads to a question about optical mouse, with no mention of tilde expansion. Can you please explain that?

Comment: Good answer. It summarizes basically what `bash` manual states in the `Tilde Expansion` section. +1

Comment: Sorry, I'm so used to using intra-site links in unix.SE as in `[link](/a/146697)` that I didn't realise we were on a different site here. The link should be to [there](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/146697)