# opencv python fails to load image

Tags: scripts, python, paths

I am following this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

The suggested code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to load an image located in my desktop so I changed the

```
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
```

line to this line:

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/Desktop/1.jpg',0)
```

when I run the code through terminal it produces error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/sohib/Documents/OpenCV/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 312
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: /home/sohib/Documents/OpenCV/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:312: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Have I included the wrong path to the image in the `imread` part?

How can I solve this issue?

Notes:

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.LTS

The tutorial documentation is for OpenCV 3.0.0, but I am using 3.2.0

Comment: I am pretty sure `'/home/Desktop/1.jpg'` does not exist. It should be `'/home/yourname/Desktop/1.jpg'`, unless *Desktop*  is your name :). ***don't*** use `$HOME` or `~`.

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The path you are using

I am pretty sure `'/home/Desktop/1.jpg'` does not exist. It should be `'/home/yourname/Desktop/1.jpg'`, unless *Desktop*  is your name :).

#### Using paths in a python script in general

You are probably confusing `/home` with `$HOME`  ***which you also cannot use***, just like `~`.

In a python script, [you cannot simply use relative- or variable paths](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890415/why-couldnt-i-use-instead-of-home-username-when-giving-the-file-pat/890419#890419).