# Why can't I cd to a quoted tilde ('~')?

Tags: command-line, bash

Writing my first script so I'm sure this is a basic question, but can someone please explain to me why I can:

```
cd ~
cd bin
cd ~/bin
cd 'bin'
```

But not

```
cd '~'
cd '~/bin'
```

I need to `cd` to a directory path with a space in one of the directory names, so I need the quotes (it's Windows `Program Files` under wine). I can get around it with two `cd` commands, but why can't I put `~` in quotes?

If I type `cd '~'` (or `cd "~"`) I get:

```
bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Ask yourself this: if if *didn't* work that way, how would you `cd` into a directory named `~`?

Comment: As a sidenote, if you're writing a script you should rather use absolute paths and avoid `cd` alltogether. Use variables to store pathnames you don't want to type multiple times, e.g. `pf=~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/; cp /path/to/file "$pf"`

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Why would a sensible system allow you to name a directory '~'?  How about a directory named '/'?  (Of course I realize that just having a directory called "Windows Program Files" means we're probably not dealing with a sensible system :-()

Comment: @jamesqf: Why would a sensible system presume to know better than me what I want to name my files and directories? Also, I never understood why Unix went with magic in-band signaling of path component separators and path terminators. What's wrong with a file/directory named `/` or `NUL`?

Comment: Thank you @dessert, I do appreciate that it is better not to have side effects but using a full path didn't work. Because of the '~' issue though...now it does!

Comment: @jamesqf Following this logic Ubuntu is not a sensible system – did you try `touch \~`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag presumably `cd ./~`

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Maybe because having a set of allowable filename characters and a disjoint set of path/command characters makes life much simpler for everyone.  Personally, I can't understand why spaces were ever allowed.  (Other that the Windows compatibility thing, but that just pushes the question off on Microsoft.)

Comment: @jamesqf Just to note that historically, Unix filesystems allowed any char in a filename except '/' (path separator) and '\0' (NUL - string-termination char) - as Jorg notes. No other restrictions. There have been many Unix filesystem implementations, so introducing restrictions in any one of them would have broken compatibility and increased complexity - and been seen as "weird"! And '~' expansion was only introduced comparatively recently in csh and more widely in bash,  files/dirs with '~' chars in are not unknown (eg myfile~ as a backup for myfile).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As @karel noted in his answer, `~` is a special character and expanded by Bash into the current user's home directory. See [Bash's manual on "Tilde Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion), or search for the headline "Tilde Expansion" in the man page (`man bash`).

Any kind of quotation around the `~` prevents this tilde expansion.

---

To answer your question about how you still can use it to `cd` into a directory with spaces in its name, there are a few alternatives:

- Omit quotes and escape the spaces with backslashes instead:

  ```
  cd ~/foo/spaces\ are\ cool/bar
  ```
- Quote the rest of the path, but omit them around the tilde and the first slash:

  ```
  cd ~/"foo/spaces are cool/bar"
  ```

  As you see, you can concatenate quoted and unquoted strings in Bash by simply writing them next to each other without any spaces in between.
- Use the environment variable `$HOME` instead of the tilde, which still gets expanded inside "double quotes" (but not 'single quotes'):

  ```
  cd "$HOME/foo/spaces are cool/bar"
  ```

Comment: @rexkogitans `~'/...'` won't work and isn't what this answer has. `~/'...'` or `~/"..."` will work.

Comment: tld;dr: because thats shell syntax

Comment: @hvd thanks. Fixed typo. This is the most complete answer and also explains how to solve what the OP wants to do. `~/'path'` is the way to go.

Comment: @hvd just little of curiosity, why wouldn't `~'/...'` work? The slash isn't a special character so it seems it should work either inside or outside the quotes.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Have a look at the Bash manpage's section about "Tilde Expansion". The relevant paragraph of that is also quoted in dessert's answer below. TL;DR: Tilde expansion takes place if the first character in a word is an unquoted tilde, then everything between that tilde and the next unquoted slash is considered the "tilde prefix". If this prefix is not a valid thing like +, -, a number, or a user name (quotes in there are not allowed either), the expansion fails and you get a literal ~ character.

Answer (score 18):

~ is a special character that is interpreted by the shell as the logged in user's home directory. '~' is interpreted by the shell as a literal ~ character, not as the logged in user's home directory because enclosing a string inside two single quote characters results in that string being interpreted as a literal text string.

Comment: `~` is not an alias in the sense `bash` interprets it: *Aliases  allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.*. As I explain in my answer below, it's rather an expansion.

Answer (score 16):

This is a `bash` feature called **Tilde Expansion**. Citing [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13):

> If  a  word  begins  with an **unquoted tilde character** (`~'), all of the
>          characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or  all  characters,  if
>          there  is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none of
>          the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the  characters  in  the
>          tilde-prefix  following the tilde are treated as a possible login name.
>          If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced  with  the
>          value  of  the  shell  parameter  HOME.   If  HOME  is  unset, the home
>          directory of the user  executing  the  shell  is  substituted  instead.

For the expansion to work the tilde character `~` needs to be unquoted, else the character is taken literally and `cd` fails if there is no directory named `~` present in the current directory. See [this entensive answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) for an explanation of quoting in `bash`. If you need to quote part of the path, you can therefore:

1. quote at least the characters that need quoting with single quotes, e.g.

   ```
   ~/dir' 'with' 'spaces/
   ```

   or

   ```
   ~/'dir with spaces/'
   ```
2. quote at least the characters that need quoting with double quotes, e.g.

   ```
   ~/dir" "with" "spaces/
   ```

   or

   ```
   ~/"dir with spaces/"
   ```
3. quote only the characters that need quoting with backslashes , e.g.

   ```
   ~/dir\ with\ spaces/
   ```

Tilde Expansion has some more interesting features, e.g.:

- `~+` expands to the value of `PWD`, i.e. the current working directory
- `~-` expands to the value of `OLDPWD`, i.e. the previous working directory
- `~john` expands to the home directory associated with the login name “john”

Answer (score 3):

#### Explore using `echo` command

The easiest way of exploring how things work in bash is with the `echo` command. In the case of `~` use this:

```
$ echo ~
/home/rick
$ echo '~'
~
$ echo "~"
~
$ echo `~`
bash: /home/rick: Is a directory
```

As you can see, when you single quote or use double quotes around `~` it is interpreted literally as a string and not expanded as a variable. When you use backticks (`) it is executed as a command and generates an error message.